# Fourier coefficients in $L_1$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f∈L_1[0,\pi]$. Consider the Fourier coefficient $\{c_n\}$ in trigonometric system $\{\sin(nx)\}$.

1)Is it necessary to converge series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |с_n|$?

2)Under what conditions does the series is converge $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n^2$

As it appears, in 1) I need example for which this series diverges. But I cant come up such example.
And I have no idea about 2)

Comment: Consider (1) Take $f=1_{[0,{\pi \over 2}]}$. (2) $f \in L^2[0,\pi]$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks! I know that when $f \in L^2[0,\pi]$ then the series is converge but how to explain that if we take function from $L_1$ then the series is diverges?

Comment: If $f$ is also in $L^2$ then the coefficients are square summable. If the coefficients of $f$ are square summable, then $f$  is in $L^2$. So, if $f$ is in $L^1$ then the coefficients are square summable **iff** $f$ is also in $L^2$.